# Array contains value of other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

So I'm using Angular and I got a form where I can enter some emails.
I send those emails and if they already exists if return a error message with the emails that are in use.

The objects from the form looks like this:

```
0: Object 
  email: "email@gmail.com"
  name: "My Name"
1: Object 
  email: "other@email.com"
  name: "My Other Name"
```

So for example if `email@gmail.com` is already in use I retrieve the following error from my API:

```
data: Array[1]
   0: Object
     email: "email@gmail.com"
message: "Some email addresses are already in use."
```

I've managed to use `pluck` from `underscore.js` where I get an array of the emails.

That's the point where I'm stuck. I want to check if the email from my form object does contain a value from the array of used emails. If it does contain a value I want to add `used: true` to the relevant form object.

So let's say `email@gmail.com` is in use, I want my form object to be:

```
0: Object 
  email: "email@gmail.com"
  name: "My Name"
  used: true
1: Object 
  email: "other@email.com"
  name: "My Other Name"
```

Comment: What is the problem to set object.used = true; in your API when you are sending response?

Comment: It's a SPA, so the form object is just client-side and the API does respond with a message and the data which contains the emails that are in use.

Comment: Have you access to code of API?

Comment: Yup, you're right I was thinking to hard. I can just check in php and return the whole object with used indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data structure looks like that, you can call the API, get the response and then iterate over your array of e-mails checking if they're present in the response from the API.

To do this you can use simple `for` loops, or even the `Array.profotype.forEach` method. Assuming that the `for` statement is the most stable method, I'm giving you an example of it:

```
// myData is the data array containing the various objects which have email and name
// myResponse is the response object retrieved from your API call

for (var i=0; i < myResponse.data.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < myData.length; j++) {
        if (myResponse.data[i].email == myData[i].email) {
            myData[i].used = true;
        }
    }
}
```

After the above code is executed, your form data object will look like this:

```
myData = [
    { 
        email: "email@gmail.com",
        name: "My Name",
        used: true
    },
    {
        email: "other@email.com",
        name: "My Other Name"
    }
];
```

Comment: For some reason it only appends `used: true` on the first X where the email is matched. If there is an unmatch middleway it doesn't append `used: true`. Never, u made a typo as well :P